# Error while using Pywebhdfs in Hortonworks

Tags: rest, webhdfs, hortonworks-sandbox

I first opened the rest server on port 8000 using

```
/usr/hdp/current/hbase-master/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start rest -p 8000 --infoport 8001
```

Then wrote this code in python:

```
from pywebhdfs.webhdfs import PyWebHdfsClient
hdfs = PyWebHdfsClient(host='192.168.56.101',port='8000',user_name='maria_dev')
my_file='user/maria_dev/creating.txt'
hdfs.create_file(my_file,'My name is awesome')
```

Then I run this on my anaconda environment and get this error:

> Raise errors.PyWebHdfsException(msg=message)
>     pywebhdfs.errors.PyWebHdfsException: b' '